# Can someone clone your github repository without being counted in the visitors of the repository?

Tags: github

My GitHub repository shows that it's been cloned 7 times by 4 different users, but it shows that there's only 1 unique visitor to the same repository. How come that's possible?

Comment: Where are you seeing visitors? I don't think GitHub publishes traffic with that kind of granularity.

Comment: There's a tab 'insight' under your repository where you can go to traffic which shows you this information, like the number of views, clones, and unique visitors, and clones. You can read about it here [link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository)

Comment: Same doubt. My GitHub repository shows 7 unique cloners and 1 unique visitor.

Answer (score 6):

Visitors are people who visit your github page. Clones are when people do `git clone`, which doesn't involve visiting the site at all.

Comment: But to know about my repository they should've viewed it at least one time, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Here, clone this: `git@github.com:github/hub`

Comment: @DeeptiSingh: Not necessarily. I clone git repos all the time without ever visiting the github page, via npm, or `go get`, or any other countless number of package managers. To say nothing of people who visited your page 6 months ago, and now are re-cloning in a CI/CD pipeline, or similar.

Comment: @Flimzy, replying to OP's comment: "to know about my repository they should've viewed it at least one time, right?" Sorry, should have mentioned them.

Comment: @Chris Oh, I understand now.

Comment: how does it possible that one repo have only one visitor(its the creator who created the repo) and repo is having more than 16 Unique cloners ?  i don't clone my own repo then how someone else (16 more users) can clone ? i don't share link to my repo to anyone. and this happend within just two days?

Answer (score 4):

I think [this](https://github.community/t/7-unique-cloners-for-my-repo/123766/2?u=imambungo) makes the most sense:

> It’s very common to have 6 or 7 unique cloners on almost every public repo, because there are several projects out there that routinely clone all public repos. Some organizations do it to scan for API keys or other credentials accidentally made public.
>
> There are also projects that clone everything for archival purposes, such as:
>
> http://ghtorrent.org/ 389
>
> https://www.gharchive.org/

Answer (score -1):

[image]

In this official documentation example from github, number of cloners are less than number of visitors.

source: https://docs.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository

Comment: Maybe because the cloners cloned it a couple of time (Even if all 229 cloners cloned it 5 times it'll be around 1145 clones). What I'm asking is how come it's possible that the number of visitors on my repo is less than the number of unique cloners, I haven't shared any link. In the example you provided #unique visitors > #unique cloners

Comment: Yea, I got what you are asking. The scenario you are referring to is different from the image above. Your scenario seems logically impossible unless someone has url to your git repo and are cloning without visiting. Weird!

Comment: What you said (clonebots) depressed me until I looked at my least popular repo compared to the others. It shows much lower clone rates than my more mainstream repos, so I think I can be sure it is not all robocloning. (hey, I just made to new words there).

Comment: it happened with me also, github is not safe, keep the repo private, even then who knows if there is a way to clone that also,